# How can i get a Type of a Variable and store it in a Template Function/Class

Tags: c++, templates, typeid

Im trying to store the name of a Variable and use this for a templated Class
But also this should be also very flexible with every Class/ type : whatever (For an Alocater) and Ive nothing found about this yet.

Here is some example Code of one of my tries:

```
#include<iostream>

template<typename T>
struct a{
    T*Data;

    a(T*Data):Data(Data){}
}

int main(){
    int i = 10;
    a<int>* obj1 =new a<int>(&a);

    //Later

    std::string Dat_Type= typeid(*obj1->Data).name();
    a<Dat_Type> obj2;//This Doesnt work 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

A string containing the name of a type is not the same as a type.  The former exists only at runtime while the latter exists only at compile time.

What you can do is add a type alias to `a` that you can pass to another template:

```
template <typename T>
struct a {
    using value_type = T;
    //...
};

int main() {
    a<int> obj1;

    // Later

    a<decltype(obj1)::value_type> obj2;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/64caaeb11f32b5df)

If you can't modify your `a` class for whatever reason, you could use partial template specialization to extract the correct type:

```
template <typename T>
struct a_traits {};

template <typename T>
struct a_traits<a<T>> {
    using value_type = T;
};

int main() {
    a<int> obj1;

    // Later

    a<a_traits<decltype(obj1)>::value_type> obj2;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/28c332606af27411)

---

Of course, if you're declaring a second object of the exact same type, you don't need to do either of those things.  You can just use `decltype`:

```
int main() {
    a<int> obj1;

    // Later

    decltype(obj1) obj2;
}
```

[Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/469a56d0fbbb3625)